# AndroidStudio preferences vs shell path variables

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, path-variables

I don't understand the difference between the path variables which you set in Android Studio Preferences which can be seen below and ones set in `zshrc/bashrc`.

[image: Path Variable Setting]

I add this path in but when trying an ADB command, it is not recognized.

[image: Error]

However, since i'm using zsh shell, same thing applies for bash. I add/export the PATH variable like i'm sure most people are familiar with.

[image: zshrc]

As seen in last line, this is same path that was added to the AndroidStudio preferences, however now as you can see below. ADB is found!

[image]

What exactly is the
`Android Studio -> Preferences -> Appearance&Behavior -> Path Variables`?

Since it has `KOTLIN_BUNDLED` and im able to run `kotlinc` command in shell, it would make sense one could add ADB here but apparently not.

What is difference between these `Path Variables` and the `Path Variables` added to `zshrc` or `bashrc`?

PS: `mirror` is just an alias for an adb command